# Site base path sharing between Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a very simple question related to site base-path. I have multiple Javascript scripts which load on page call. They call multiple AJAX calls to the site. However, when I deploy it on my local machine then base-path will be `http://localhost/subfolder/xxx` and when I deploy to the actual site it will be `http://mywebsite.com/subfolder/xxx`. so I have to correct it in all the scripts.

Is there any way I can define a variable i.e. `basepath= "xxx"` and reuse it in other scripts when the page loads?

Comment: Isn't easier to do a Ajax call to the `url = '/subfolder/xxx'` instead?

Comment: I guess in the first java-script file (that loads on page first or you can put this file in head) and set a unique variable like basepath = 'yourdomain' (that name is not used in any of the files) and the java-script that loads after the first file can access that "basepath" variable in your code then in ajaxurl you can use url : basepath + "yoururl"

Comment: somehow this "/subfolder/xxx" ajax is not working for me. I am still trying to figure out the way to set the unique variable "the way you defined above" in the file header. let me get back once i investigate further.  thnx